# Email form in a window alert or similar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to achieve is creating a form that will open when pressing the link, where people can put their email and then email me directly from that form. I want that form to be displayed in let's say a window alert that opens when clicking the icon link. I was also wondering if there are ways I can stylize this form. I am not expecting to use CSS and HTML only, I can also use Java Script.

Comment: you can't do it with javascript alone. you'd need to do a ajax post to a server side script which sends the email and return a confirmation/error message to feedback on the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: https://jsfiddle.net/3p8akoy8/

thats not a pure JS alert, but a popup window.
With a bit love and CSS you'll be able to make it loke pretty neat.

```js
$('.openForm').click(function() {
    $('.popup').addClass('visible');
});
$('.closeForm').click(function() {
    $('.popup').removeClass('visible');
});
```

```css
.openForm {
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.popup {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.visible {
    display:block;
}

.popup .form {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:white;
    border:solid 1px #ddd;
}

.popup .closeForm {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ccc;
}

.popup .closeForm:hover {
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="openForm">Click Me</div>
<div class="popup">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="closeForm">X</div>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail...">
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: here's an [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/3p8akoy8/2/) with a send button and a little test-response in JS. Usually you would either use the form tags action attribute or an AJAX call with js.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was lookign for, although it appears there is no "send" button to send the email?

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much it! So I will only ask you how to set my email as the email to send the text to. And how to make the "Message from" and "text" not appear as I press send?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bootstrap modal, and put the form in there.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Yeah it is pretty cool as well! but what form should I insert in it? Does HTML form support email sending as well? I thought it was for login and password stuff only..

Comment: HTML can't send e-mails by itself. You'll want to use a server-side script for this. Here's an example for a php solution.
http://www.formget.com/send-an-email-on-form-submission-using-php/